# jQuery Button Only Works Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal was to create a simple button which once clicked would hide/show a navigational menu, and change the footer's padding alternatively, I'd have used `toggle()` if not for the latter condition.  How do I make the button serve both purposes, that is first hide the menu and decrease footer padding, and then  upon another click show the menu and increase the padding, and so forth, so that upon clicking the button one effect would occur and upon another click the other? Any help, suggestions, or alternatives, will be much appreciated.

```
function collapseOrCondense(event) {
    if ($('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu:visible')) {
        $('#footer').css({
            'padding-bottom': '2.5%'
        });
        $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').hide();
    } else {
        $('#footer').css({
            'padding-bottom': '5.5%'
        });
        $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').show();
    }
};
$('#footer').append('<button type=button class=cbutton>*</button>');
$('#footer .cbutton').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': '1%',
    'top': '1%',
    'width': '2%',
    'height': '1.5%'
});
$('#footer .cbutton').on('click', collapseOrCondense);
```

Comment: `.click` and `.on('click',...)` are functionally identical.

Comment: question is kind of unclear

Comment: And the JS is incomplete, too.

Comment: just edited, I tried making the purpose more clear

Comment: I left the jquery wrappers/tags out since this is wrapped in drupal.behaviors and I wanted to keep it as simple as it could it be, if there any other jquery mistakes I apologize.

Comment: I would try attaching the click event to the button, adjustin the padding on the footer could be moving the click box.

Comment: my mistake inputting the code, it's actually ('#footer .cbutton') corrected above, problem persists

Comment: Could you provide a basic a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: You can do all of this just by changing the class on the footer - like `$("#footer").removeClass("collapsed").addClass("opened")` ... then your CSS can take care of hiding / positioning / changing your padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an example here. http://jsfiddle.net/wdakLfcc/2/

```
var visible = true;
function collapseOrCondense(event) {
if (visible) {
    $('#footer').css({
        'padding-bottom': '2.5%'
    });
    $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').hide();
    visible = false;

} else {
    $('#footer').css({
        'padding-bottom': '5.5%'
    });
    $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').show();
    visible = true;
}    

};
$('#footer').append('<button type=button class=cbutton>*</button>');
$('#footer .cbutton').css({
'position': 'absolute',
'left': '1%',
'top': '1%',
'width': '2%',
'height': '1.5%'
});
$('#footer ').on('click', '.cbutton', collapseOrCondense);
```

On button click different effect will be played - Collapse Or Condense.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from my analysis that your conditional is always evaluating to true. I propose you add some other form of indicator to better distinguish the toggle.

I jury rigged a simple implementation: http://plnkr.co/edit/y8BugzI89s0i5kxM95H9?p=preview

```
function collapseOrCondense(event){
  if($('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').css('display') === 'block'){
    $('#footer').css({'padding-bottom':'2.5%'});
    $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').hide();
  }
  else{
    $('#footer').css({'padding-bottom':'5.5%'});
    $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu').show();
  }
}
```

The aforementioned snippet is one way of handling this case given my demo environment -- I am sure there are many ways but the underlying problem is your condition (at least in my scenario with the data provided) is always evaluating to true.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line you have:

```
if ($('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu:visible')) {
```

Because that will return a jQuery object with one or zero elements inside. You could fix that by adding `.length`. But I think using the `is` function is more clear.

Here I fixed that, and applied some changes that may help you to do the same in a more concise manner:

```js
function collapseOrCondense(event) {
    var menu = $('#block-panels-mini-footer-nice-menu');
    $('#footer').css({
        'padding-bottom': menu.is(':visible') ? '2.5%' : '5.5%'
    });
    menu.toggle();
}
$('<button type=button class=cbutton>*</button>').css({
    'position': 'absolute',
    'left': '1%',
    'top': '1%',
    'width': '2%',
    'height': '1.5%'
}).on('click', collapseOrCondense).appendTo('#footer');
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yj5evps2/

Comment: any and all help is welcomed, thank you for the alternative + answer definitely helps